# RewriteCond not working properly

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Home_Page/sort/(all|action|romance|thriller|crime|sci-fi)/(1|2|3|4|5)
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9])$  kl.php?genre=$2&page_no=$3 [NC] [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Home_Page/sort/(all|action|romance|thriller|crime|sci-fi) 
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  kl.php?genre=$2 [NC] [L]
```

The request uri passes the required query strings

```
if reruest uri is /Home_Page/sort/(all|action|romance|thriller|crime|sci-fi) rewrite to ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  kl.php/?genre=$2
if request uri is  /Home_Page/sort/(all|action|romance|thriller|crime|sci-fi)/([0-9])$ rewrite to ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  kl.php/?genre=$2&page_no=$3
```

Comment: I am in a kind of rush situation. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thannk in advance.

Comment: Not clear what you exactly want. Can you clarify a bit more.

Comment: basically i want index.php/?type=this&how_much=x to show up like domain/type/how_much

Comment: And what parameter values like `this` and `x`?

Comment: this = some string and x = constant value   eg. domain/coke/23

Comment: Right but while loading URL as `domain/type/how_much` how will your PHP code get `this` value?

Comment: my real url is to be like: domain/sort/action/4 where 4 is page no

Comment: Ok edit your question and provide examples of URLs you want to show in browser and their actual internal URLs that your code will get.

Comment: request uri: domain/homepage/action/5 and actual url: index.php?genre=action$page_no=5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?genre=([^\s&]+)&page_no=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ homepage/%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^homepage/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?genre=$1$page_no=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: RewriteRule ^sort/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?genre=$1$page_no=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

Comment: still displays the index.php on the browser]

Comment: actually i have one more rewrite rule above these two rules. does that interfere because they are kind of related.

Comment: Where is this `sort` coming from? When I asked you to write all the examples and you commented `request uri: domain/homepage/action/5` so I am unable to understand all of your requirements unless you write **each and every case** in your question.

Comment: also i have done RewriteBase /Home_page/ so i dont have to include homepage in the rule everytime

Comment: Question is still unclear as I don't what you mean by `rewrite to ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  kl.php/?genre=$2`

Comment: rewrite to ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$ means sort/action and rewrite to ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9])+) $ means sort/action/page_no

Comment: the request comes from a php page that says a href = sort/action/page-no

Comment: the page_no will be passed as a int value

Comment: the rule works for all: sort/genre but when i pass the page_no value it doesnt display : sort/genre/4 insted index.php?genre=sort&page=4

Comment: Is it `page` or `page_no`? Earlier you wrote `page_no`

Comment: page_no is the actual one

Comment: Read you previous comment where you wrote: **sort/genre/4 insted index.php?genre=sort&page=4**

Comment: what i meant was i have written page_no everywhere in the actual code here. i am still trying to figure out.

Comment: ok what is happening when you enter `http://domain.com/index.php?genre=sort&page=4` in your browser?

Comment: i get to the page i want

Comment: like action/4 i get there

Comment: See I cannot provide endless and directionless support via comments section as unnecessary long comments are not liked by Stackoverlow moderators. After hours of discussion and providing a working rules I am unable to clearly understand what is the problem you're facing.

Comment: haha... i am noww getting error 404 on home_page/sort/action/1 but not on home_page/sort/action

Comment: Because above rule I wrote supports `/homepage/action/5` as per your original requirement.

Comment: isnt it supposed to support from 1 to 5?

Comment: precisely stationg, my problem is /home_page/sort/action/page_no returns a error 404 (page_no is from 1-10)

Comment: Hope you're reading my comments. Despite several nudges you still haven't clarified your requirements and only interested in typing endless comments after comments.

Comment: i am sorry. /homepage/sort/action should take me to the list of all action movies where there are about 10 pages for each genre. /homepage/action/3 should take me to the respective page of that genre of movies. /homepage/action is working fine but /homepage/action/3 is giving me error 404

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Home_Page/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Home_Page/sort/(all|action|romance|thriller|crime|sci-fi)$
RewriteRule  ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)$  kl.php?genre=$2 [NC] [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/Home_Page/sort/(all|action|romance|thriller|crime|sci-fi)/([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^sort/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?genre=$1$page_no=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Not as an answer, click on `edit` link below your question and provide these rules there.

Comment: also: /sort/sci-fi/1 works but /sort/action/1 doesnt